# Install library built with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

First time bazel user here. I've compiled a library [1], but I'm missing how to install it to prefix /usr/local.

Sure I can always copy it around. But what is the bazel way of doing it?

[1] https://github.com/google/jwt_verify_lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/google/bazel_rules_install. The feature set seems to  support install prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a standard Bazel solution here.

If the build result is self-contained, copying looks acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If on Linux, consider https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg. It can produce rpm or deb package, which can be then installed by the respective package manager.